# va_arg macro isn't promoting integer to double

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am working on the following code, using variadic functions to perform standard deviation.

When I am passing all double value arguments, my variadic function is computing the desired result. However, let's say I make the last value to *25* instead of *25.0*, the value being printed in the variadic function corresponding to this value is *0* or some junk value. And this is resulting in variadic function not calculating the standard deviation correctly.

Compiler :GCC, 
System : Windows 10, 64-bit

My question is, why isn't *25* *int* value promoted to *25.0* *double* value in the *va_arg* macro?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>

double sample_stddev(int count, ...) 
{
    /* Compute the mean with args1. */
    double sum = 0;
    va_list args1;
    va_start(args1, count);
    va_list args2;
    va_copy(args2, args1);   /* copy va_list object */
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        double num = va_arg(args1, double);
        printf("%f \n",num);  /*printing each number passed to this function*/
        sum += num;
    }
    va_end(args1);
    double mean = sum / count;

    /* Compute standard deviation with args2 and mean. */
    double sum_sq_diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        double num = va_arg(args2, double);
        sum_sq_diff += (num-mean) * (num-mean);
    }
    va_end(args2);
    return sqrt(sum_sq_diff / (count-1));
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf("%f\n", sample_stddev(4, 25.0, 27.3, 26.9, 25.0));
}
```

Comment: Because the caller isn't psychic. Only the _default argument promotions_ are applied to variadic arguments.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like that `sample_stddev` function is actually calculating the _population standard deviation_, not the _sample standard deviation_.

Comment: The called function does not know the type. How should any conversion be done in that case? It is **your** job to ensure reading same type as was passed by caller. Then you can convert whatever you want.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Converted the *population standard deviation* to *sample standard deviation*